# Appium, Instruments crashed on startup

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, appium

When I updated Xcode from 6.4 to 7.2 my Appium UI Automation stopped working, with instruments crashing.

Appium: 1.4.13

Xcode: 7.2

Here are the error logs:

```
info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPhone 6 (8.4)
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 6 (8.4)" /var/folders/23/nmp6lms102vg0s25m1322t400000gp/T/116125-731-112rfi4/Time.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/bogdan.shubravyi/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {"DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7/InstrumentsShim.dylib","LIB_PATH":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7"}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code null
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] dyld: could not load inserted library '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7/InstrumentsShim.dylib' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7/InstrumentsShim.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x100C77000, size=0x00001000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7/InstrumentsShim.dylib

info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

info: [debug] Cleaning sim data files

info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase F023F482-F636-4535-B4B8-2F272F799EEF and timeout: 2000

info: [debug] Cleaning app data files
...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Are you able to access the `instruments` in ways other than appium script? 2. Also please make sure you have Use `Native Instruments Library` checked under `Advance` settings for IOS platform in Appium's UI. 
3. Enable `UI Automation` setting in setting--developer

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about "Native Instruments Library", ++ to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure you have `Use Native Instruments Library` checked under Advance settings for IOS platform in Appium's UI and ensuring `Enable UI Automation` setting in setting--developer helps as mentioned in the comments.