# Appium - Getting started on Mac OS

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I have problems setting up an Appium test framework on Mac OS.

My system settings are:

- Mac OS (El Capitan)
- xCode 7.2.1
- Appium GUI 1.4.13
- python 2.7.10

First question: Does the Appium GUI offer everything?
So do I still need an selenium webdriver installation?
Or do I need any client bindings?

I want to run the example test `ios_simple.py` test for the example app `TestApp`.
What I do so far is:

1. I start the Appium GUI
2. I launch the Appium server by GUI
3. I start the example test script by terminal python `ios_simple.py`

If I do so, I cannot start the Appium inspector by GUI.
I receive the following errors:
[image]
[image]

So where is my fault? What am I missing to do?

Hope anybody can help me. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Are you able to access the `instruments` in ways other than appium script? 2. Also please make sure you have `Use Native Instruments Library `checked under `Advance settings` for IOS platform in Appium's UI. 3. `Enable UI Automation` setting in setting--developer

Comment: could be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633001/appium-instruments-crashed-on-startup/35646176#35646176

Comment: Also a point over App Path : could you double check the path that you are providing in the GUI.

Comment: Okay. I checked the `Use Native Instruments Library` in Appium GUI Advanced settings. Now it works as far as I can see.
But in Appium documentation it is declared as deprecated. So why do I have to check this setting? Why does it not work without?
Where do I enable `UI Automation`? In xCode? In Appium? Is it a command line parameter?

Comment: Could possibly be the version of Appium you are using and the version for which you are going through the docs.

Comment: could you please close this(rollback the thread) if the problem is solved

Comment: `Use Native Instruments Library` solved this problem.