# Appium: Attempting to change event horizon while disengage

Tags: appium, appium-ios

As I'm new to Appium on IOS, I couldn't find the issue

I'm facing this issue.

---> I have given the app path as .app file on simulator----Still fails

---> I have used .ipa file on real device--- Still fails.

Every time the app opens and crashes in a loop on startup.

```html
[INST STDERR] 2016-03-29 15:58:51.215 instruments[2825:122645] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage
2016-03-29 15:58:51.216 instruments[2825:125164] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Failed looking up pid of launched process

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
```

Mac OS-10.11.4
Xcode 7.2.1
App OS-8.4
Simulator: iphone 5s
Real device: Iphone 5c

Could anyone help me with this please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633001/appium-instruments-crashed-on-startup/35646176#35646176

Comment: I have tried same thing as mentioned in the link by Making sure  "Use Native Instruments Library" checked under Advance settings for IOS but still happens same issue. open and crashes in a loop.

Comment: sharing the comment from the post again 1. Are you able to access the instruments in ways other than appium script? 2. Also please make sure you have `Use Native Instruments Library` checked under `Advance` settings for IOS platform in Appium's UI. 3. `Enable UI Automation` setting in setting--developer

Comment: Hi @nullpointer, Yeah I'm able to do all those from the comment but still the app crashes. Thanks

Comment: I have got solved with the help of developers... 
1. **.app file on simulator:** The .ipa file was build using the latest Xcode and .app file was build using the old Xcode so the simulator didn't detect the .app file until updating the Xcode and building the .app for simulator. 
2. **.ipa file on real device:** The .ipa file was build for 9.3 OS versions and I was trying to install on 9.0.1OS version so I was facing issue in installing the file. 
Thanks again